# Parse a colon separated string with pyparsing

Tags: python, string, pyparsing

This is the data:

```
C:/data/my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK
C:/data/my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK
./data/my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK
```

And I would like to get this result

```
[C:/data/my_file.txt.c, 10, 0x21, name1, name2, 0x10, 1, OK]
[C:/data/my_file2.txt.c, 110, 0x1, name2, name5, 0x12, 1, NOT_OK]
[./data/my_file3.txt.c, 110, 0x1, name2, name5, 0x12, 10, OK]
```

I know how to do that with some code or string split and stuff like that, but I am searching for a nice solution using pyparsing. My problem is the :/ for the file path.

Additional Question I use some code to strip comments and other stuff from the records so the raw data looks like this:

```
text = """C:/data/my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK
C:/data/my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK
// comment
./data/my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK
---- 
ok
"""
```

And i strip the "//", "ok", and "---" before parsing right now

So now I have a next question too the first:

Some addition to the first question. Till now I extracted the lines above from a data file - that works great. So I read the file line by line and parse it. But now I found out it is possible to use parseFile to parse a whole file. So I think I could strip some of my code and use parseFile instead. So the files I would like to parse have an additional footer.

```
C:/data/my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK
C:/data/my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK
./data/my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK: info message

-----------------------
3 Files 2 OK 1 NOT_OK
NOT_OK
```

Is it possible to change the parser to get 2 parse results?

Result1:

```
[['C:/data/my_file.txt.c', '10', '0x21', 'name1', 'name2', '0x10', '1', 'OK'],
 ['C:/data/my_file2.txt.c', '110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '1', 'NOT_OK'],
 ['./data/my_file3.txt.c', '110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '10', 'OK']]

Ignore the blank line   
Ignore this line => -----------------------
```

Result 2:

```
 [['3', 'Files', 2', 'OK’, '1', 'NOT_OK'],
 ['NOT_OK’],
```

So I changed the thes Code for that:

```
    # define an expression for your file reference
one_thing = Combine(
    oneOf(list(alphas)) + ':/' +
    Word(alphanums + '_-./'))

# define a catchall expression for everything else (words of non-whitespace characters,
# excluding ':')
another_thing = Word(printables + " ", excludeChars=':')

# define an expression of the two; be sure to list the file reference first
thing = one_thing | another_thing

# now use plain old pyparsing delimitedList, with ':' delimiter
list_of_things = delimitedList(thing, delim=':')

list_of_other_things = Word(printables).setName('a')
# run it and see...
parse_ret = OneOrMore(Group(list_of_things | list_of_other_things)).parseFile("data.file")
parse_ret.pprint()
```

And I get this result:

```
[['C:/data/my_file.txt.c', '10', '0x21', 'name1', 'name2', '0x10', '1', 'OK'],
['C:/data/my_file2.txt.c','110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '1', 'NOT_OK'],
['./data/my_file3.txt.c', '110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '10', 'OK', 'info message'],
['-----------------------'],
['3 Files 2 OK 1 NOT_OK'],
['NOT_OK']]
```

So I can go with this but is it possible to split the result into two named results? I searched the docs but I didn´t find anything that works.

Comment: Can you change the delimiter or quote the areas that conflict with your grammar?

Comment: If number of fields is fixed and extra colons occurs always in first element, quick workaround may be to use [`string.rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rsplit) with `maxsplit`, e.g. `line.rsplit(":", maxsplit=NUM_OF_FIELDS)`.

Comment: I want to use http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/ so @rogalski I know how I can solve the problem in the way you explain, thanks

Comment: @AIG no I cannot change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn´t found a solution with delimitedList and parseFile but I found a Solution which is okay for me.

```
from pyparsing import *

data = """
C: / data / my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK
C: / data / my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK
./ data / my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK: info message

-----------------------
3 Files 2 OK 1 NOT_OK
NOT_OK
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':

# define an expression for your file reference
entry_one = Combine(
    oneOf(list(alphas)) + ':/' +
    Word(alphanums + '_-./'))

entry_two = Word(printables + ' ', excludeChars=':')
entry = entry_one | entry_two

delimiter = Literal(':').suppress()
tc_result_line = Group(entry.setResultsName('file_name') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName(
    'line_nr') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName('num_one') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName('name_one') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName(
    'name_two') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName('num_two') + delimiter + entry.setResultsName('status') + Optional(
    delimiter + entry.setResultsName('msg'))).setResultsName("info_line")

EOL = LineEnd().suppress()
SOL = LineStart().suppress()
blank_line = SOL + EOL

tc_summary_line = Group(Word(nums).setResultsName("num_of_lines") + "Files" + Word(nums).setResultsName(
    "num_of_ok") + "OK" + Word(nums).setResultsName("num_of_not_ok") + "NOT_OK").setResultsName(
    "info_summary")
tc_end_line = Or(Literal("NOT_OK"), Literal('Ok')).setResultsName("info_result")

# run it and see...
pp1 = tc_result_line | Optional(tc_summary_line | tc_end_line)
pp1.ignore(blank_line | OneOrMore("-"))

result = list()
for l in data.split('\n'):
    result.append((pp1.parseString(l)).asDict())
# delete empty results
result = filter(None, result)

for r in result:
    print(r)

pass
```

Result:

```
{'info_line': {'file_name': 'C', 'num_one': '10', 'msg': '1', 'name_one':   '0x21', 'line_nr': '/ data / my_file.txt.c', 'status': '0x10', 'num_two': 'name2', 'name_two': 'name1'}}
{'info_line': {'file_name': 'C', 'num_one': '110', 'msg': '1', 'name_one': '0x1', 'line_nr': '/ data / my_file2.txt.c', 'status': '0x12', 'num_two': 'name5', 'name_two': 'name2'}}
{'info_line': {'file_name': './ data / my_file3.txt.c', 'num_one': '0x1', 'msg': 'OK', 'name_one': 'name2', 'line_nr': '110', 'status': '10', 'num_two': '0x12', 'name_two': 'name5'}}
{'info_summary': {'num_of_lines': '3', 'num_of_ok': '2', 'num_of_not_ok': '1'}}
{'info_result': ['NOT_OK']}
```

Answer (score 2):

See embedded comments for pyparsing description:

```
from pyparsing import *

text = """C:/data/my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK
C:/data/my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK
// blah-de blah blah blah
./data/my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK"""

# define an expression for your file reference
one_thing = Combine(
    oneOf(list(alphas.upper())) + ':/' + 
    Word(alphanums + '_-./'))

# define a catchall expression for everything else (words of non-whitespace characters, 
# excluding ':')
another_thing = Word(printables, excludeChars=':')

# define an expression of the two; be sure to list the file reference first
thing = one_thing | another_thing

# now use plain old pyparsing delimitedList, with ':' delimiter
list_of_things = delimitedList(thing, delim=':')

parser = OneOrMore(Group(list_of_things))

# ignore comments starting with double slash
parser.ignore(dblSlashComment)

# run it and see...
parser.parseString(text).pprint()
```

prints:

```
[['C:/data/my_file.txt.c', '10', '0x21', 'name1', 'name2', '0x10', '1', 'OK'],
 ['C:/data/my_file2.txt.c', '110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '1', 'NOT_OK'],
 ['./data/my_file3.txt.c', '110', '0x1', 'name2', 'name5', '0x12', '10', 'OK']]
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul that´s exactly the way I am looking for. One last question - Is there a way how I can add a pattern to ignore a whole line? As an example if there is a comment in the middle of two records

Comment: See the latest changes.

Answer (score -3):

Using re:

```
myList = ["C:/data/my_file.txt.c:10:0x21:name1:name2:0x10:1:OK", "C:/data/my_file2.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:1:NOT_OK", "./data/my_file3.txt.c:110:0x1:name2:name5:0x12:10:OK"]

for i in myList:
    newTxt =  re.sub(r':', ",", i)
    newTxt = re.sub(r',/', ":/", newTxt)
    print newTxt
```

Comment: Thanks that is also a great solution but I want to use pyparsing